# Find rows in a data frame where two columns are equal

Tags: r

I'd like to select the rows in a data frame where two columns, A and B are equal. I have tried this:

```
A <- c(0,1,2)
B <- c(2,1.000001,0)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(A,B))
subset(df,A==B) # does not work
# [1] A B
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
subset(df,round(A,3)==round(B,3)) # does work
#  A        B
# 2 1 1.000001
subset(df,A==B)
```

Comment: -1 for vague "didn't work" - error message?

Comment: Make this a reproducible example please... +1 for vagueness

Comment: "didn't work" in this case meant is gave the following output:<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any point in posting a reproducible data set. As I wrote in the comment to the answer below, the problem was due to rounding. As soon as I make a reproducible set, this becomes blindingly obvious. Anyway, I'll post it in a new comment

Comment: reproducible example:A<-c(0,1,2);B<-c(2,1.000001,0);df<-as.data.frame(cbind(A,B));subset(df,A==B) #does not work;subset(df,round(A,3)==round(B,3)) # does work

Comment: " As soon as I make a reproducible set, this becomes blindingly obvious." This is exactly one of the reasons why you should make a reproducible example. Often, reducing a problem to its core leads to the answer.

Comment: Yes, well I know that with hindsight, but I thought I had just used the wrong command/syntax, and making a reproducible dataset would be overkill. If I had to make a reproducible dataset every time I had a little problem, I'd never make any progress. I found the problem in about 30 secs after the answer from nzcoops below, but it took me at least 10 mins to make the dataset example.

Comment: Couldn't someone have said "you're using the right syntax so perhaps check the data or post a reproducible dataset" instead of just downvoting me for not doing it in advance for something that seemed trivial ?

Comment: Maybe. But "didn't work" is one of those phrases that presses the wrong buttons. I've reversed my downvote now it's corrected.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
mteq <- mtcars[mtcars$gear==mtcars$carb, ]
```

Comment: But I suspect this is a dupe.

Comment: Thanks. I did search SO for an answer first. Sorry it it's a dupe. Actually I did use this method already, but it didn't work, which I've now discovered is due to rounding, so I have to use iv[round(iv$p.lower,3)==round(iv$p.upper,3),]

Comment: To compare floating point numbers, a standard method is `abs(x - y) < tol` where `tol` is a small number, typically `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)`.